# Taylor series convergence of $f(z)=\int^z_0 \frac{\zeta-\sin(\zeta)}{\zeta^2+4} \, d\zeta$ at $a=2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> $$f(z)=\int^z_0 \frac{\zeta-\sin(\zeta)}{\zeta^2+4} \, d\zeta$$

I am supposed to find the convergence radius of its Taylor series at point $a=2$.

I can find the radius in simple cases by finding the distance from the nearest non-analytic point, but I am not sure how to handle the current situation. I believe that it is not necessary to actually find the series, also, integrating it seems to get a bit ugly. How can I figure out the points where the function fails to be analytic? I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: $f'(z) = \frac{z-sinz}{z^2 + 4}$ (fundamental theorem of calc).  I would say f(z) has poles at $\pm$ 2i.